# Jetpack navigation does not navigate to other destination

Tags: android, data-binding, android-jetpack-navigation

I am using jetpack navigation in two different activities each with its navigation host. I have Main activity which everything just works fine and Setup activity which have 2 fragments, one has a button which should navigate to other fragment when clicked .

The activity's code is as follows:

```
class SetupActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val navController by lazy { findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment) }
    private lateinit var appBarConfig: AppBarConfiguration

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivitySetupBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_setup)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        appBarConfig = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfig)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfig) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

Below is activity's xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".ui.SetupActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_setup">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/setup" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Below is code of first fragment which is also a start Destination

```
class ConfirmClassFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val binding = FragmentConfirmClassBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.fragment = this

        return binding.root
    }

    fun navigate() {
        toast("clicked") //this get called
        val direction = ConfirmClassFragmentDirections.actionConfirmToSetup()
        findNavController().navigate(direction) //THE PROBLEM IS HERE
        //findNavController().navigate(R.id.setup)
    }
}
```

I am using data binding to call `fun navigate()` as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="fragment"
            type="com.nux.ui.fragments.ConfirmClassFragment" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/spacing_middle">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{() -> fragment.navigate()}"
            android:text="@string/continue_" />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

and this how navigation xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/setup"
    app:startDestination="@id/confirm">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/setup"
        android:name="com.nux.ui.fragments.SetInfoFragment"
        android:label="@string/setup"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_set_info" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/confirm"
        android:name="com.nux.ui.fragments.ConfirmClassFragment"
        android:label="@string/data_confirmation"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_confirm_class">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_confirm_to_setup"
            app:destination="@id/setup" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

When I click button fun gets called but nothing happens! What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From the code i can see you have the same id for 3 elements in the navigation graph.

@id/setup should only be used once and please change the name of the navigation graph from setup to something else.